# Django form for querying database. Is form.py needed and how to leave fields empty for query?

Tags: forms, validation, python-3.x, django-forms

I would like to have an input form where a user inputs either an `incident_id` or a `equipment_id` or both. The problem I have now is for example, if I fill in `incident_id` and leave `equipment_id` blank, the query will return no hits even when `incident_id` finds a match, because my query uses blank `equipment_id` in the search. How can I set it up so that when I leave a field blank, it doesn't use it in the query? Do I need to validate this data? I'm not inserting any of it into the db.

I know Django forms uses POST, but in this instance I feel that GET is more appropriate, which means I don't have to use Django forms, but does that mean I also don't have to validate the data? Or should I just use POST anyway and validate that data with Django forms? I'm sorry this is so conceptual. I'm not finding many good answers online.

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Incident(models.Model):
incident_id = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
equipment_id = models.ForeignKey(Equipment, blank=True)

class Equipment(models.Model):
        equipment_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
        manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)
        equipment_category = models.ForeignKey(Equipment_Category)
        validated= models.BooleanField(default=True)
        in_service_date = models.DateTimeField('in service date', default=timezone.now)
```

**view.py**

```
@login_required
def search_incidents_query(request):

            if request.method == 'GET':

                            incident_id_query = request.GET.get('incident_id')
                            equipment_id_query = request.GET.get('equipment_id')

                            try:
                                            incident_id = str(incident_id_query)
                            except ValueError:
                                            incident_id = None
                            try:
                                            equipment_id = str(equipment_id_query)
                            except ValueError:
                                            username = None

                            list = [incident_id,equipment_id]

                            if all(x is None for x in list): #check if `list` contains only None
                                            incident_list = None #this in case the query comes back empty
                            else: #perform query

                                            incident_list = Incident.objects.filter(incident_id=incident_id, equipment_id=equipment_id)
                                                                                                                            )                              
                            return render(request, 'search_incidents_query.html', { 
                                            'incident_list' : incident_list
                            })
```

**search_incidents_query.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block content %}
<br>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <!-----INPUT FORM------------------->
    <form method='GET' action='/search_incidents/'>
        <div class="row">   
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label>Incident ID</label>
                <input type="text" name="incident_id" value="{{ incident_id_query }}" class="form-control"/>
            </div>              
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">               
                <label>Equipment ID</label>
                <input type="text" name="equipment" value="{{ equipment_id_query }}" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The query

You should use a Q object for similar queries.

```
from django.db.models import Q 

Incident.objects.filter(
     Q(incident_id=incident_id) | Q(equipment_id=equipment_id)
)
```

More on [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#q-objects).

Also, IMO this code needs to live in some Form class. If it was me, I would have put this code in some

### The form

```
class IncidentSearchForm(forms.Form):
    incident = forms.CharField(required=False)
    # ModelChoiceField because we want django to do the validation for us
    # TextInput because the default widget is a select tag
    equipment = forms.ModelChoiceField(Equipment.objects.all(), required=False, widget=forms.TextInput)  # TextInput because

    def clean(self):
         # I'd use the clean method to force the user to provide either an incident or equipment value

    def search(self):
        return Incident.objects.filter(
              Q(incident_id=self.cleaned_data['incident']) | 
              Q(equipment_id=self.cleaned_data['equipment'])
        )
```

### The view

- Why aren't you using Class Based Views already?
- `username = None`. Wat?

You **should** use a form because [never trust user input](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Don%27t_trust_user_input).

```
@login_required
def search_incidents_query(request):
    form = IncidentSearchForm(request.GET or None)
    incident_list = None     
    if 'equipment' in request.GET or 'incident' in request.GET:
         incident_list = None  # Or maybe Incident.objects.none()  
         if form.is_valid():
            incident_list = form.search()

    return render(request, 'search_incidents_query.html', {'form' : form})
```

### The template

```
<form method='GET' action='/search_incidents/'>
    <div class="row">   
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            {{ form.incident }}
        </div>              
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">               
            {{ form.equipment }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You can use a widget on the form to add `form-control` class to the fields.

Comment: Could you elaborate on  `def clean(self):
         # I'd use the clean method to force the user to provide either an incident or equipment value.` Can you clean data in forms.py or views.py?

Comment: The cleaning *should be* done in the Form class. The form.clean() method is automatically called in your *form.is_valid()*

Comment: The issue I'm having now is if I leave one of the fields empty my query errors because it doesn't like to use ''(empty string) in a search. How can I get around this?